# How to export SMS and contacts from cell phone to ubuntu

Tags: phone, contacts, sms

I am trying to export my text messages and my contacts from a cell phone(an Adroid Samsung Galaxy mini and a Sony Ericsson w810i) to my ubuntu laptop.

Firstly I tried using `Wammu` and I was easily able to export my text messages from the Sony Ericsson W810i(not android phone).

When it comes to the Android Samsung I cannot even retrieve the messages let alone export them, however I can retrieve every calls and only the contacts that are saved in SIM card.

I also tried with `Xgnokii` which for some reason cannot start up as well as `gMobileMedia` which states that my phone is not supported.

I also tried with `gnome-phone-manager` but what I get is

```
thanos@thanos-laptop:~$ gnome-phone-manager

** (gnome-phone-manager:14036): CRITICAL **: bluetooth_chooser_button_set_property: assertion `bluetooth_verify_address (g_value_get_string (value)) || g_value_get_string (value) == NULL' failed
** Message: New connection device is empty (not changed)
** Message: New connection device is empty (not changed)
** Message: No device!
** Message: Exiting connect thread
```

I also tried other ports, but no phone can be found.

The only way to see my messages is via the android application `airdroid`, but I am not able to save my messages and contacts in my PC.

Is there a way to save my text messages and contacts in my PC?

Comment: why don't you try `sms backup and restore` [by Ritesh sahu] from playstore. It export the file in xml format and also an xsl stylesheet to read the messages.

Comment: @Web-E: Thank you very much for your comment! I used it to back up my text messages and it worked~ Thank's! But how to save my contacts?

Comment: i use `Easy Backup` with dropbox, you should try that.

Comment: I use SMS Backup+, which backs up call log and SMS to Gmail.

Answer (score -2):

to export from android, search the google store for "contact export". this will save your contacts in csv, vcf, pdf to your phone. you then copy from phone to pc via any means you prefer: wifi, blue, usb.